# Windows Live Authenticaton

Tags: c#, security, windows-live

Is it possible to make HttpWebRequest query to windows Live ID enabled web sites? What is the method of authentication knowing username and clear text password? Could not found anything like that in Live ID SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of live, and any federated identity solution is you never see the password (and often the username), you simply know a user authenticated and get a unique reference for that user - Live takes the authentication information, not you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which service you want to use you will find that the API's are slightly different (or non-existent). Which service(s) are you trying to use?

It is possible to completely emulate a web browser using HttpWebRequest, just don't forget to re-send the cookies with each request:

http://www.menet.name/blog/christophe/archive/2008/05/29/sending-receiving-cookies-with-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse.aspx